# Laravel keeping track of individual cell of a row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

For convenience, laravel generates an `updated_at` column on each table, which is really amazing. I can easily keep track of which *row* has been updated. But what if I wanted to introduce a Log/History/Activity feature in my application?

Currently laravel answers to this question:

> **When** was a row updated?

How can I get an answer to this question:

> **What** in a row was updated?

Comment: Make separate table named activity log and keep track of changes in the database table.

Comment: `keep track of changes` - How? Any hint and/or demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to keep track changes in user table then, you schema looks like,

**Users**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Now, create activity log table like,

**Activity Log**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('activity_log', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->increments('user_id');
        $table->enum('changed_column',['name','email','password']);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

Now, whenever you change column of users table then add details of which column changed in to activity log table. Based on time stamps you can track which column of user is changed.

I hope you understand.

Comment: Based on time stamps you can track which column of user is changed - Are you sure? I think with timestamps I can only keep track of rows...

Comment: In case of more than one time changes of a particular user you have many record in activity log table associated to that user then latest row in activity log table of that user corresponds the change. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your tables  save last-updated field names in a json field